# some doubts in PHP include() <b>Function</b>

Tags: php, include

Hello guys
I have one question ...

1. Is it possible to run PHP with the `include()` Function if disabled?
2. Is possible that the include() `Function` you can not find a file that really exists?

Thank you

Comment: and also some doubts in your question ...?

Comment: @Hary, if you're going to bother editing the question at least edit the formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I don't think so, no - `include` is a language construct and as far as I know, can't be disabled.
2. Yes, if you don't have the proper rights to read the file.

You should probably add some more information about your specific situation to get more specific help.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it's not a function, it's a language construct
2. No

[include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: @Lelis as Pekka noticed, permissions should checked too, not only existing of file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why would you want to disable includes?
2. Yes it is, if you don't specify the path correctly (in relation to the current php file).

Comment: Thanks for the info

I do not want to disable the include just wanted to make sure that the server would disable if possible.

wanted an assurance that the file actually available were loaded without problem, without having to use 'file_exists'


responses were highly useful

Answer (score -1):

`include` is usually not disabled. You almost always need and include, and it is a good idea to use `require` or `require_once` if the file you want to use is required for your code to run